# Why won't my Whirlpool washer go to high speed spin?

Tags: washing-machine

Whirlpool Duet model wfw9750ww01 won't ever get up to high speed spin even with an empty washer. It will go to hi speed spin in diagnostics.

When it's time for spin, the machine always rotates alternating directions a few times, then turns the drain pump on and slowly spins up. It gets up to a fair it stops and starts over.

Comment: Is this a new machine?  If so send it back.  Is this a new problem on an older machine that work right before?

Comment: I have an older model and it behaves that way. It doesn't reach "full speed spin" until after it goes through the slow spin/pump cycle a few times. Have you waited long enough for it?

Comment: The machine is about 10 years old, It never goes to high speed spin except in diagnostics.

Comment: It does go to a medium speed spin after it goes through the slow spin/pump cycles, if its got a load or not. It seems to be stuck in unbalanced load with or without a load. but if you run in diagnostics it goes to high speed every time.

Comment: There are no error codes. As I said above when running machine empty there is no shaking when this is done. The four shock absorbers were replaced the springs are unbroken there is no sagging and there is only very little play in the bearing, the drum spins by hand with very little resistance. The CCU was replaced and the level sensor and the MCU. The machine is sensing an  unbalanced load when there is none. Also the washer was ran through a diagnostics cycle and it runs on hi speed spin every time.

Answer (score 1):

First, check the [Whirlpool Duet Washer Job Aid](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1783650/Whirlpool-Duet-Ggw9200l-Series.html) for the meaning of the **error codes, which you should include in your question**.

That said, it might due to shaking from being out of balance. "The unbalance detection routine occurs.. while basket spin is accelerating from 40 to 400 rpm...  If the Motor Control Unit senses an unbalanced condition, the drive motor is stopped."

A few likely causes of excessive shaking:

- There are two suspension springs. If one breaks, the drum tilts to one side and drops lower.
- There are four shock absorbers. Over time, they can deteriorate, causing excessive shaking.
- The drum bearing can be loose.

[image: Duet Washer Suspension]

The first two can be easily fixed with comparatively inexpensive parts, using the *Job Aid* and readily-found online videos. **Use caution, particularly with electrical safety and with spring replacement. This is not a good DIY project for a beginning learner.**

However, replacing the drum and/or bearing are *not* a DIY project, nor is it inexpensive. For a 10 year-old washer, it's likely not worthwhile.